# How to include Publications in europeCV.lyx from a BibTeX database?

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I am wondering if I can include publication list using `BibTex Database`. I know that I can write the publications manually but I don't want to if I have a large list of publications.

Comment: Perhaps you should run through http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/BibTeX/biblioexample.pdf - I don't see how europeCV would be especially different.

Comment: @Stefan, Thanks for your response. I have managed it. But i am facing two more problems. One is to reduce vertical space between list of publications and contents of CV (For example Whole CV is takes 1.5 pages and publications starts on the second page. I need publications on the same page not on separate page). And other problem is that when i include Section "Publications" i also receive sub-heding of references also. I only need publications hedding not references.

Comment: @Sean Allred, can u help me in this regard?

Comment: Without some detail of what you are actually doing this is not likely to get an answer. I'm therefore marking as 'unclear'.